# How do I get the graphql Checkout id from an Abandoned Checkout using the Shopify api?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I want to use Shopify's API to retrieve an abandoned checkout, find the correct graphql checkout id, and then edit that checkout. I can't figure out how to get an checkout id from an abandoned checkout.

What I've tried:

1. The [api rest admin](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-01/resources/abandoned-checkouts#get-checkouts?limit=1)

This will return me an object that looks something like this:

```
{
    "abandoned_checkout_url": "https://merch.journey.com/71444005163/checkouts/ac/457fd128a8fce5ab646936466d3d8427/recover?key=457fd128a8fce5ab646936466d3d8427",
    "cart_token": "457fd128a8fce5ab646936466d3d8427",
    "customer": {
        "id": 6851444670763,
        "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Customer/6851444670763"
    },
    "id": 36628892451115,
    "landing_site": "/checkouts/do/7d076603979a6c17104c47e4e01e4b2e",
    "name": "#36628892451115",
    "token": "2dd918556a3300df0cd1579651bb2093",
}
```

2. Using the token (457fd128a8fce5ab646936466d3d8427) and key (457fd128a8fce5ab646936466d3d8427) I can generate a graphql admin id gid://shopify/Checkout/{token}?={key}. So gid://shopify/Checkout/457fd128a8fce5ab646936466d3d8427?=457fd128a8fce5ab646936466d3d8427
   Creating the checkout id like this ONLY works if I created the checkout using the embedded graphql app in my store. If a user naturally went to my site, the abandoned_checkout_url key and token will always return this when queried from graphql.

```
{
  "data": {
    "node": null
  }
}
```

3. I can use the id from the abandoned checkout to query shopify like so:

```
query {
  node(id: "gid://shopify/AbandonedCheckout/36628892451115"){
    id ... on AbandonedCheckout {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

or
`

```
{ 
  abandonmentByAbandonedCheckoutId(abandonedCheckoutId: "gid://shopify/AbandonedCheckout/36629026275627"){
    id
  }
}
```

Both will successfully return every time, but I can't get it to associate back with a checkout or a cart.

I've got both unauthenticated read_checkouts and write_checkouts scopes along with every checkout scope for the admin api. We can't access the checkouts scope from the admin api because we're not an approved shopify app.

I just want to know how to go from abandoned carts to checkouts and do that consistently. What might I be missing?